# Change "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." message

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-4

I'm sure I'm missing something silly here. I'm trying to replace the **non-debug** error screen that Laravel throws when there's an exception. It seems to be ignoring the code below (placed in `start/global.php`):

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);
    if(!Config::get('app.debug')) {
        return Response::view('errors.exception', ['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 500);
    }
});
```

Why would it ignore that? And was I supposed to do something elsewhere as well?

#### Bit of clarity:

I'm testing this with a `QueryException` (`HY000`). But surely this should not make a difference?

Using Laravel 4.2

Comment: It took me forever to figure out a proper way to override that message. Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41753753/470749

Answer (score 2):

It'd be hard to say without seeing your system, but my first guess would be there's another call to `App:error` made after yours that overrides what's you're trying to do in `app/global.php`.

I just wrote about how Laravel [sets up it's error handling recently](http://alanstorm.com/laravel_error_handler).  After reading that article (or maybe skipping it and diving in), the way I'd debug this would be to hop into

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php
```

and look at the definition of `callCustomHandlers`.  This is the method that calls any handlers setup via `App:error`

```
protected function callCustomHandlers($exception, $fromConsole = false)
{
    foreach ($this->handlers as $handler)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Your handler will be in the `$this->handlers` array.  I'd add some temporary debugging code to this class (the class may be in Laravel's single combined optimized file) to determine

1. If your handler fails the `handlesException` test
2. If there's another handler added to the queue after your that "wins" and sends a response.

It also never hurts to start with a

```
App::error(function()
{
    exit(__FILE__);
});
```

and then build out your error handler until it stops being called.  That way you know what part of it Laravel's having a problem with.

Comment: I think I'll give that a try when I get home this afternoon.

Comment: Right, so I did a `dd($this->handlers)` to see what's in there - but it's an empty array... So I assume that it's throwing the error before it populates the `handlers` variable?

Comment: @MikeAnthony That sounds like a possibility.  Try a debug_print_backtrace (wrapped in pre tags or viewed with the View -> Source menu).  This will give you the call stack to the error handler.

Comment: That's quite a messy dump - not sure how to read it. I can see that it is listing the Exception though... Just can't see the order of things (unable to prettify it easily either). The Exception is the first thing in the file though...

Comment: @MikeAnthony Try to format it like this, and post it as part of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555383/understading-stack-trace-from-error-log-magento (add newlines to the # signs if you don't have them)

Comment: Still makes for a really large segment... I'll post the whole thing  into a paste quick.

Comment: Though, there already are new lines before each `#`... And the whole thing is half a meg...

Comment: Then again, I'll just enable debugging to get the trace.

Comment: @MikeAnthony Error handlers should definitely be setup by that point. There's something weird going on if the custom handlers array is empty and I'm afraid I don't have enough experience with the framework to guess what's going on.  If I was debugging this myself I'd make sure my start.php was being loaded and/or included in the compiled.php next.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In `app/global.php` there is a default error handler setup.  You will want to remove that to use yours, or just modify that one.

Check this out for more information... http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-errors

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to do it... Surely `QueryException` extends `Exception`? As such, it should work with `Exception` anyway... yes?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, you are correct.  Let me change the answer.

Comment: That doesn't do it either. Even went paranoid and did a `clear-compiled` and `optimize` just to make sure. I tried using both error handlers (one for `Exception` and one for `QueryException`), and then again with only my `QueryException`). No luck. It could be because my sessions are stored in the database - if that even makes any difference.

Comment: To clarify - I'm testing to see what happens when the database goes down or is wiped.

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  You don't have the code which would be throwing the error in a try catch block would you?