# Custom error page not showing on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I am trying to display a custom error page instead of the default Laravel 5 message :

> "Whoops...looks like something went wrong"

I made a lot of search before posting here, I tried this solution, which should work on Laravel 5 but had no luck with it : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/change-whoops-looks-like-something-went-wrong-page

Here is the exact code I have in my `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file :

```
<?php namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use View;
use Bugsnag\BugsnagLaravel\BugsnagExceptionHandler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {

    protected $dontReport = [
        'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException'
    ];

    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        return parent::report($e);
    }

    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        return response()->view('errors.defaultError');
    }

}
```

But, instead of displaying my custom view, a blank page is showing. I also tried with this code inside `render()` function

```
return "Hello, I am an error message";
```

But I get same result : **blank page**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the response create a route for your error page in your Routes.php, with the name 'errors.defaultError'. for example

```
route::get('error', [
    'as' => 'errors.defaultError',
    'uses' => 'ErrorController@defaultError' ]);
```

Either make a controller or include the function in the route with

```
return view('errors.defaultError');
```

and use a redirect instead. For example

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    return redirect()->route('errors.defaultError');
}
```

Comment: It worked. You just forgot a quote in your code in `'uses' => 'ErrorController@defaultError ]);` but thank you very much

Comment: Do you know why you cannot simply return the `errors.defaultError`  page in Handler.php `render()` function?

Comment: @Justin I have the same question... Have you discovered why? When I use a `route` with `redirects` works well, but doesn't work when I return the `view` directly. (*a view with blade template*)

Comment: This hides the normal HTTP response and redirects the browser to a different resource.

Comment: @tomloprod returning `response()->view` works as well, but if you try to use the default blade error page that comes with `extends('errors::layout...')`, you may run into a blank page or whoops error page depending on your web server config. The issue is that the default laravel error templates use a custom hint path.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly agree with everyone who wants to customize the error experience in Laravel such that their users never see an embarrassing message such as 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong.'

It took me *forever* to figure this out.

### How To Customize the "Whoops" Message In Laravel 5.3

In `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, replace the entire `prepareResponse` function with this one:

```
protected function prepareResponse($request, Exception $e)
{        
    if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {            
        return $this->toIlluminateResponse($this->renderHttpException($e), $e);
    } else {
        return response()->view("errors.500", ['exception' => $e]); //By overriding this function, I make Laravel display my custom 500 error page instead of the 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong.' message in Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler
    }
}
```

Basically, it's almost identical to the original functionality, but you're just changing the `else` block to render a view.

In `/resources/views/errors`, create `500.blade.php`.

You can write whatever text you want in there, but I always recommend keeping error pages very basic (pure HTML and CSS and nothing fancy) so that there is almost zero chance that they themselves would cause further errors.

### To Test That It Worked

In `routes/web.php`, you could add:

```
Route::get('error500', function () {
    throw new \Exception('TEST PAGE. This simulated error exception allows testing of the 500 error page.');
});
```

Then I would browse to `mysite.com/error500` and see whether you see your customized error page.

Then also browse to `mysite.com/some-nonexistent-route` and see whether you still get the 404 page that you've set up, assuming you have one.

Comment: There is no such function `prepareResponse` in the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file. and yes i am using 5.3. i have the following function `report`, `render` and `unauthenticated`. did you added it yourself? and by the way, can you post your entire `Hadler.php file?` just to be sure that we have the same thing? Thanks!

Comment: @Eitan I probably meant that you'd be overriding the function of the class that that file extends.  So just try adding it in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` and see if it works. See how your file says `class Handler extends ExceptionHandler`? You can browse to `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php` and see the original `prepareResponse` function there. By creating your *own* `prepareResponse` in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, you'll be overriding the original.

Comment: I placed the code in the `render` function, and it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

I have two error pages - 404.blade.php & generic.blade.php

I wanted:

- 404 page to show for all missing pages
- Exception page for exceptions in development
- Generic error page for exceptions in production

I'm using .env - APP_DEBUG to decide this.

I updated the render method in the exception handler:

**app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
    }

    if ($this->isUnauthorizedException($e)) {
        $e = new HttpException(403, $e->getMessage());
    }

    if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
        // Show error for status code, if it exists
        $status = $e->getStatusCode();
        if (view()->exists("errors.{$status}")) {
            return response()->view("errors.{$status}", ['exception' => $e], $status);
        }
    }

    if (env('APP_DEBUG')) {
        // In development show exception
        return $this->toIlluminateResponse($this->convertExceptionToResponse($e), $e);
    }
    // Otherwise show generic error page
    return $this->toIlluminateResponse(response()->view("errors.generic"), $e);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

on Larvel 5.2 on your `app/exceptions/handler.php` just extend this method `renderHttpException` ie add this method to `handler.php` customize as you wish

```
/**
 * Render the given HttpException.
 *
 * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException  $e
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e)
{

   // to get status code ie 404,503
    $status = $e->getStatusCode();

    if (view()->exists("errors.{$status}")) {
        return response()->view("errors.{$status}", ['exception' => $e], $status, $e->getHeaders());
    } else {
        return $this->convertExceptionToResponse($e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't handle 500 errors, which this question asks about. Instead, you need to use: `protected function convertExceptionToResponse(Exception $e) {
        $status = $e->getCode();
        if ($status == 500) {
            $view500 = config('app.debug') ? "errors.500_dev" : "errors.500";
            return response()->view($view500, ['exception' => $e], 500);
        } else {
            return parent::convertExceptionToResponse($e);
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 5.4, you can place this code block inside **render** function in Handler.php - found in app/exceptions/Handler.php

```
  //Handle TokenMismatch Error/session('csrf_error')
    if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        return response()->view('auth.login', ['message' => 'any custom message'] );
    }

    if ($this->isHttpException($exception)){       
        if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
            return response()->view("errors.404");
        }
        return $this->renderHttpException($exception);
    }

    return response()->view("errors.500");
    //return parent::render($request, $exception);
```

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low quality because it is code-only.  Please explain it.

Answer (score -1):

The typical way to do this is to just [create individual views for each error type](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#custom-http-error-pages).

I wanted a dynamic custom error page (so all errors hit the same blade template).

In Handler.php I used:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    // Get error status code.
    $statusCode = method_exists($e, 'getStatusCode') ? $e->getStatusCode() : 400;
    $data = ['customvar'=>'myval'];
    return response()->view('errors.index', $data, $statusCode);
}
```

Then I don't have to create 20 error pages for every possible http error status code.

Comment: Your index view extends from a blade template? As I know (*and I don't know why*) returning the view directly (*without a route*) inside the `render` method of the `ExcepcionHandler` doesn't work well with blade template.