# Laravel 5.2 - customize error "Whoops, looks like something went wrong"

Tags: laravel, handler

How can I change the error page "**Whoops, looks like something went wrong.**"? I want to show my page 404 inside *errors* folder
my handler is simple:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: It took me forever to figure out a proper way to override that message. Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41753753/470749

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you're already inside of **app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    return response()->view('errors.custom'); 
}
```

Comment: He said he wants to change all of his "Whoops" errors to his 404 template. At least, that's what I understand? If not, then I read it wrong. But yes, this will show the custom error for all errors.

Comment: oh lord, no man you are right! i think that i assumed that he want to show a view for every error because its the best approach i guess, but he didnt ask for that.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought! I tend not to question people, just give them the answer they want :D

Answer (score 2):

change that to

```
  public function handle($request)
  {
      try
      {
          return parent::handle($request);
      }
          catch(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $e)
      {
          return response()->view('Viewname', [], 404);
      }
      catch (Exception $e)
      {
          $this->reportException($e);

          return $this->renderException($request, $e);
      }
  }
```

Comment: thank you, I solved with the guide https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#http-exceptions

Comment: close the question then or declare it as answered

Answer (score 0):

Access the `handler.php` in the `App\Exception` folder and change the default code to the code below.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{

      if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
        if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
            return response()->view('404', [], 404);
        }
        if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 403) {
            return response()->view('403', [], 403);
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```