# how to show 500 internal Server error page in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to show the page **500 internal server error** Page. when user had syntax error mistake in project can anyone help me? if i do some mistake in syntax i want to show that particular blade.

Comment: You might also want to see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41753753/470749

Comment: you can find proper info on this link https://belanki.com/programming/laravel/a-guide-to-create-custom-404-and-500-page-in-laravel-in-4-steps/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to create handler to catching `FatalErrorExceptions` in your handler like below code:

**Handler**
In `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

    // 404 page when a model is not found
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }

    // custom error message
    if ($e instanceof \ErrorException) {
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    } else {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

**View**
See `resources/views/errors/500.blade.php`. If not exist then create it.

You can get more detailed OR other ways from [Laravel 5 custom error view for 500](http://laravel.io/forum/02-19-2015-laravel-5-custom-error-view-for-500)

Comment: Glad to help you..Cheer...!

Comment: The else statement could be removed because if the "if" statement is false, it will still go to the last return of the function.

Answer (score 8):

In your `resources/views/errors`  folder create a file named `500.blade.php`.

> Laravel makes it easy to display custom error pages for various HTTP
>   status codes. For example, if you wish to customize the error page for
>   500 HTTP status codes, create a  `resources/views/errors/500.blade.php`. This file will be served on all 500 errors generated by your application.

The problem is that Laravel will only do this automatic rendering of error pages for exceptions that are instances of `HttpException`. Unfortunately when your server throws an error (method does not exist, variable undefined, etc) it actually throws a `FatalErrorException`. As such, it is uncaught, and trickles down to the `SymfonyDisplayer()` which either gives you the trace (debug true) or ugly one-liner 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong' (debug false).

To solve this you have add this to your `render` method to `app/Exceptions/Handler`

```
# /app/Exceptions/Handler.php

# use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException;

# public function render($request, Exception $e)

$exception = FlattenException::create($e);
$statusCode = $exception->getStatusCode($exception);

if ($statusCode === 404 or $statusCode === 500) {
    return response()->view('errors.' . $statusCode, [], $statusCode);
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#custom-http-error-pages)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since this one works and is included in the official Laravel documentation.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is simple, just replace your render() method in Exceptions\Handler.php file with:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param \Exception               $exception
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return $this->renderJson($request, $exception);
    }

    if ($this->shouldReport($exception) && app()->environment('production')) {
        $exception = new HttpException(500, $exception->getMessage(), $exception);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

It will show 500 page if app in production environment. You will need to have 500.blade.php view in your resources/views/errors folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // app/Exceptions/Handler.php

    protected function prepareResponse($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if($this->isHttpException($e) === false && config('app.debug') === false)     {
            $e = new HttpException(500);
        }

        return parent::prepareResponse($request, $e);
    }
```

Like @Amit said

> The problem is that Laravel will only do this automatic rendering of
>   error pages for exceptions that are instances of HttpException.

So my solution is to replace whatever exception that is not HttpException by a HttpException.

Answer (score 0):

in app\Exceptions\Handler create the following method:

```
protected function convertExceptionToResponse(Exception $e)
{
        $e = FlattenException::create($e);
        return response()->view('errors.500', ['exception' => $e], $e->getStatusCode(), $e->getHeaders());
}
```

it will override the one in the parent class (Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler) that displays the whoops page.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.4, you could override `prepareException` function in your `app\Exception\Handler.php`:

```
/**
 * @inheridoc
 */
protected function prepareException(Exception $e)
{
    $exception = parent::prepareException($e);

    if(!config('app.debug')) {
        if(!$exception instanceof HttpException && $this->shouldReport($exception)) {
            $exception = new HttpException(500);
        }
    }

    return $exception;
}
```